# add a row dynamically immediately below another in a table using clone function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I would actually dynamically add a row in my table just after the clicked line. By using the clone in JavaScript, I've realized that it actually added all the other lines. Would it be possible to add just the clone of the last line and not the other previous ones?

This is my script

```
$("#insertRow").live('click',function () {
    var $curRow = $(this).closest('tr'),
    $newRow = $curRow.clone(true);
    $curRow.after($newRow);
});
```

Comment: use class insted of id selector

Comment: I did this jsfiddle: _http://jsfiddle.net/k0fn916g/_